# Alert in lync when i receive mail from particular mail id

Tags: outlook, office-2007, lync, lync-2010

We are using Lync 2010 and Microsoft outlook 2007.

If i receive a mail from particular mail id, I should be alerted by lync.

Is that possible? how to achieve it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure - you could use [UCMA 3.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg421023.aspx) to build a bot that gets deployed to a middle-tier application server. The bot could use [Exchange Web Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb408417%28EXCHG.80%29.aspx) to monitor the users mailbox, and then start a conversation with the user when finding an email from the target user. You'd also need to build some form of administration to allow users to select which emails they are interested in.

If ultimately all you are trying to achieve is to bring attention to certain emails, then this solution is massively overengineered. Doing something client-side only using the Lync SDK is not really an option - you presumably want to be alerted to the email by a new Lync conversation, but you'd already be signed in as yourself in Lync, so who would the new conversation be from? Lync doesn't allow you to start conversations with yourself.

I think maybe leaving Lync out of the equation and implemententing e.g. an Outlook plugin would be the best way to being attention to your emails - unless there is another use case that you haven't mentioned?

Comment: I need to alert the people in cc. So i don't need to ping myself in lync. Thanks for the tip